# images displayed in the application does not appear

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have this code ImageHandler.

```
Public Class ImageHandler : Implements IHttpHandler
   Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpH
    Dim oBJDB As New DBX
    Try
        Dim oSDR As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

 oSDR = oBJDB.CreateSDRFromSQLSelect("SELECT SIGNIMAGE FROM APPUSERDTL WHERE UID =@UID")
        If oSDR.Read() Then
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(CType(oSDR("SIGNIMAGE"), Byte()))
            Dim ImageID As New SqlParameter("@UID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
             ImageID.Value = context.Request.Cookies("UID").Value
        End If
        oSDR.Close()
        oSDR = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
    Finally
        oBJDB.Close()
        oBJDB = Nothing
    End Try

End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

images displayed in the application does not appear if use this.

please help me

Comment: what did you mean in "images displayed in the application does not appear"? How did you used this handler in web application? what kind of data returns if you open just image url in web browser?

Comment: I put to ImageView in a different form, and from this handler I want to take an image file from the database and show based on who  UID is log in

Comment: if using a parameter @ UID picture does not show up, but if you use "where UID = UID" or "WHERE UID = '38 ', the picture appears

Comment: So it looks like your context.Request.Cookies("UID") doesn't has any value. and your query just throws an exception

Comment: if used context.request.querystring("UID")same..

Comment: can tell me how to take it through the handler imageurl

Comment: Please add some exception logic for logging: Catch ex As Exception context.Response.Write(ex.Message) and check again what kind of exception occurred in the query

Comment: this is code in aspx..for view image in form aplication(<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="75px" ImageUrl='~/Profile/ImageHandler.ashx'
                                           Width="76px"  />)

Comment: what kind of data returns if you simple view http://your_app/Profile/ImageHandler.ashx url in the browser? And also don't forget adding exception message into handler response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an image control in .aspx file:

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="75px"  Width="76px" />
```

and then in your .vb file:

```
      imageId as string=context.Request.Cookies("UID").Value
      Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Profile/ImageHandler.ashx?ImageId= "& imageId
```

Feel free to contact and don't forget to mark as answer that would help you.